# Should I put laravel web service in the same project with laravel web?

Tags: web-services, laravel, configuration, laravel-4

I have almost finished developing a website. Now I want a mobile version. (The mobile version is not a website, but an application that uses some feature of the website.)
So I want to build web services using laravel.

I already learned how to do that and I tested some of them, they are working fine for post and get request.

My problem is that I don't know if I should put the web service in the same project with the web project because in the web project I have `CustomerController` with route `customers` and I need to have the same **route** for the web service.

So the best practice is to  build a new project or create the web service in the same project but with different names. for example:

route `customersWS` is for web service and
route `customer` is for web

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'm working on same kind of projects, (web application for administration and RESTful service form mobile devices), both of them I have put in same project though I could easily and cleanly isolate one from the other, I have created route groupe for RESTful Api so I could avoid conflicting:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'api.v1.auth'), function(){
   Route::controller('customers', 'CustomersControllerApiV1');
}
```

For api authentication I recommend you to have a look at this [article](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/).

Comment: so you are suggesting that the route will be like this `api/customers` ?

Comment: This way you will isolate web application url which is `customers` from RESTful url `api/v1/customers`, and you will get rid of all conflicts.

Comment: and my classes names will be `CustomerController` and `CustomerAPIController` ?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent yes I think so, what cons you think this approach has?

Comment: I don't think there are cons. However, I am trying it now and will update u, +1

Comment: So, have you written different controller fro web and API ?